# Which programming language statically check the length of variable-length classes?

Tags: language-design

Which statically typed programming language exist where the length of arrays, lists, ... is statically inferred and checked? Consider the following working C# example, where this would be useful:

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] arrayOfStrings1 = { "the", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps" };  
        var arrayOfStrings2 = functionOnArray(arrayOfStrings1);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfStrings1.Length; i++){
            var string1 = arrayOfStrings1[i];
            var string2 = arrayOfStrings2[i];
            // do anything here

        }
        
    }
    
    static string[] functionOnArray(string[] arrayOfStrings){
        return arrayOfStrings.Skip(1).ToArray();
    }
        
}
```

This fails at iteration 5, as the arrayOfStrings2.Length is only 4:

> [System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
> at Program.Main() :line 14

If the language could check beforehand that arrayOfStrings2.Length = arrayOfStrings1.Length - 1, it could know before runtime, that the loop will fail. This would prevent some runtime errors and thus make programming easier.

About the possibility of checking this before runtime:
C# already checks before runtime if a nullable variable has been checked for nullability before it can be cast to the non-nullable version. Simply checking this in an if-condition is sufficient, so it somehow infers before runtime the result of a a function (here the if-condition) on the possible values of a variable. This could be implemented the same way for statically checking the length of variables.

Comment: Yes, such languages exist, no, C# isn't one of them. Now, what practical problem has that helped you to solve?

Comment: _"...it could know before runtime, that the loop will fail..."_ - how? `arrayOfStrings2` is not determined until _runtime_.  Not even static code analysis is going to pick that up.  Possibly the closest thing is Code Contracts metadata applied to `functionOnArray`  but I'm not aware of anything suitable

Comment: That is, in some way, what `foreach` does.

Comment: @Enigmativity why is that what foreach does?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem

Comment: @ZoharPeled - It automatically ensures that it doesn't go beyond the length of the enumberable.

Comment: @Enigmativity Ok, thanks. I see what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, it's called "Dependent types". There are academic languages available that support this, for instance [Idris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idris_(programming_language)).

I don't believe it's available in any commercial main stream languages.